# Symfony 2 assetic doesn't generate css files at all

Tags: symfony-forms

I've met problem with css generation

I added such code:

```
<? foreach ($asseticHelper->stylesheets(
        array('@AnglerCoreBundle/Resources/public/css/*')
) as $url
    ): ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?= $view->escape($url) ?>" />
<? endforeach ?>
```

in head of my layout.html.php and:

```
<? foreach ($view['assetic']->javascripts(
    array(
        '@AnglerCoreBundle/Resources/public/js/framework/jquery.js',
        '@AnglerCoreBundle/Resources/public/js/framework/json2.js',
        '@AnglerBackendBundle/Resources/public/js/hashchange.js',
        '@AnglerBackendBundle/Resources/public/js/location.js',
        '@AnglerBackendBundle/Resources/public/js/interfaces/*',
        '@AnglerBackendBundle/Resources/public/js/page.js',
        '@AnglerBackendBundle/Resources/public/js/ui.js',
        '@AnglerBackendBundle/Resources/public/js/main.js',
        '@AnglerBackendBundle/Resources/public/js/fader.js',
        '@AnglerBackendBundle/Resources/public/js/modal.js',
        '@AnglerBackendBundle/Resources/public/js/pages/*',
    )
) as $url
): ?>
```

above closing body tag. Problem is that when I call commands:

```
app/console clear:cache --env=dev[prod]
app/console assetic:dump 
app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug
app/console assets:install
```

assetic bundle generates only javascripts and I see them on page in both environments but css files it doesn't.

Comment: Guys! This is fantastic. `app/console assetic:dump` didn't generate css files properly because I assigned `$view['assetic']` to variable `$asseticHelper` and tried to call this: `$asseticHelper->stylesheets(...)` Never do it, at least for assetic and all helpers which need some console actions

Answer (score 0):

You need to add:

```
assetic:
    bundles: [AnglerCoreBundle, AnglerBackendBundle]
```

in your config.yml file.